# Using pandas combine worksheets, iterate through a specific column, add rows to a new list

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have an excel workbook with multiple worksheets that all have the same column headers. I want to iterate through one of the columns within each of the worksheets and add the rows to a new list (or column).

Background: Each of the worksheets represents a different community of farmers and each column of each worksheet is a piece of demographic data. I have assigned a code to each of the farmers, and I would like to get all of these codes in a list. I know that I can do it manually in excel but am trying to use pandas, python

An example of one of the worksheets within the pruning.xlsx file looks like this:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


sheets_pt = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\RRF\Desktop\pruning.xlsx",sheetname=None)
sheets_pt_read = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\RRF\Desktop\pruning.xlsx")

sheetnames_read = sheets_pt_read.sheet_names

codelist = []
for village in sheetnames_read:
    for code in sheets_pt[village]["Farmer Code"]:
        codelist.append(code)
```

After running the code. I print the codelist and the Farmer Codes from the first 5 sheets print out. Then this error message below appears...

### This is the error message I get:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance
.
.
.
KeyError: 'Farmer Code'

Would be more than happy to share entire error message if anyone is interested.

Comment: `pd.read_excel()` already creates a DataFrame, you don't need to wrap it again.

Comment: Furthermore, so if I call sheets_pt["Agosa"]["Farmer Code"] then the farmer codes for the "Agosa" sheet will be called. Is there a way to make a list of the sheet names and then iterate through that list?

Comment: It would be more helpful to create a new StackOverflow question when you have a new/different problem instead of editing the same question multiple times - even if the end goal is the same. So people having the same problem can find the question + answer, not some random answers to a question that's not there anymore.

Comment: So what do you recommend? Do you think I should close this question?

Comment: No, this is good. Just open a new one when the question changes. Have you seen [these examples for excel worksheets in pandas](https://pbpython.com/pandas-excel-tabs.html)? Maybe those can help.

Comment: Char, Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read excel file into notebook assign to pro2019
pro2019 = pd.read_excel(path_to_file, sheet_name=None)

# concatenate all of the worksheets within the file removing the index 
# from individual sheets
df = pd.concat(pro2019, ignore_index=True)

# create empty list to store farmer codes
pro_codelist = []

# iterate through the df column titled "FARMER CODE"
# append each code to pro_codelist
for code in df["FARMER CODE"]:
    pro_codelist.append(code)
```